# How to get the length of IStream? C++

Tags: c++, windows, stream

I'm creating an IStream as follow:

```
IStream* stream;
result = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(0, TRUE, &stream);
```

Then I have a CImage object that I save to this stream:

```
image->Save(stream, Gdiplus::ImageFormatBMP);
```

I need to get the size of bytes written to this IStream.

How can I do this?

There is no Length or something like this in the IStream...

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[IStream::Stat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380045%28VS.85%29.aspx) should do what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use:

```
    ULARGE_INTEGER liSize;
    IStream_Size(pStream, &liSize);
```

other functions you might find useful in this context:

```
    IStream_Reset(pStream);         // reset seek position to beginning
    IStream_Read(pStream, mem, size);
```

Answer (score -1):

Both [`IStream_Size`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-istream_size) as well as [`IStream::Stat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-istream-stat) can be used to request the size. `IStream_Size` appears to be a convenience wrapper around `IStream::Stat` (that's oddly only available as a C COM macro). If that is indeed the case then there's a lot of data queried: An entire [`STATSTG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/ns-objidl-statstg), optionally without the `pwcsName` member.

In that case, a less costly way to get the same information would be [`IStream::Seek`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-istream-seek):

```cpp
HRESULT get_size(IStream* stream, ULARGE_INTEGER& size) {
    return IStream->Seek({}, STREAM_SEEK_END, &size);
}
```

This changes the stream's current read or write pointer. If you need to save the current position you can use the following:

```cpp
ULARGE_INTEGER current{};
stream->Seek({}, STREAM_SEEK_CUR, &current);
```